# Client-side rendering with node.js and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, client-side

First of all I’m new to Node.js and React and I’ve been struggling to understand the difference between client side rendering and server side rendering.

I set up a node.js server with express using the following code :

```
var express = require('express');
var React = require('react');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

My problem is that my index.jsx is rendered on the server side and I want it to be on the client side to use React correctly.

Here's my index.jsx :

```
var React = require('react');

class index extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.db()
  }

  db() {
    this.setState({
        name: 'Marvin'
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = index
```

My componentDidMount() is not fired because it's on server side. So how can I render that on client side using my setup ?